# preference extension package to jar

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, preference

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Preferences/article.html   did somebody see this paper? and I executed the example, it is run as eclipse application successfully, however when I packaged it to jar and pushed the jar package to eclipse's plugin directory , there was no effect in eclipse, thanks for your anwser

Comment: Packaged it as a Jar how?

Comment: there has no effect in eclipse, just like not add this jar package。 however when it run as eclipse application there has the effect in eclipse platform

Comment: You must use `Export > Deployable plug-ins and fragments` to create a plugin jar

Comment: I did this and got the same result

Comment: Show us the contents of your `build.properties`

Comment: source.badwordchecker.jar = BADWORDCHECKER Plugin
bin.includes = META-INF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have the `plugin.xml` (and possibly other things) in your `build.properties`. A more or less standard `build.properties` for a plug-in would be:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           OSGI-INF/,\
           plugin.xml
```

`OSGI-INF` can be left out if you don't have that folder.

Comment: source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/   this is  contents of build.properties in  my another plugin project, but is this file not automatically generate?

Comment: source.badwordchecker.jar = BADWORDCHECKER Plugin
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\     I changed it to this and I made it ~~~ thanks so much!